# How to calculate annual probability of an event occurring on plot level?

Tags: r, biostatistics

I am working with tree data and trying to calculate the annual probability of harvesting occurring on the plot level but am struggling a bit with the concept. I formated the data that each line represents one tree that was sampled two times, in one of the years between `year1` and `year2` and `harvest` says if the tree was harvested or not in that time period. The data looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(plot=c("A","A","B","B","C"),
                 tree=c(1,1,2,3,4),
                 year1=c(2000,2000,2005,2005,2007),
                 year2=c(2002,2004,2010,2010,2014),
                 averageInterval=c(3,3,5,5,7)
                 harvest=c(0,1,1,1,0))
```

Based of of this data, I would like to calculate the annual probability of `harvest` happening on a `plot` level.